# Ractive.js variable with dash

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

Back end (WordPress) generates JSON output:

```
sizes: {
thumbnail: "150x150.jpg",
thumbnail-width: 150,
thumbnail-height: 150,
}
```

In JS I can use variable with a dash that way: `sizes['thumbnail-height']`. Unfortunately, in Ractive.js template `{{sizes['thumbnail-height']}}` does not work. How I can deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the objects keys as string then you can use the - sign. That said is a good practice to avoid it and use camelCase style. If you realize for css attributes are always translated into camel case.

```
sizes: {
    'thumbnail': "150x150.jpg",
    'thumbnail-width': 150,
    'thumbnail-height': 150,
}
// Best
    sizes: {
        thumbnail: "150x150.jpg",
        thumbnailWidth: 150,
        thumbnailHeight: 150,
    }
```

The first case still works fine with Ractive (see http://jsfiddle.net/6hd3xt6t/) using the quoted property names like `{{sizes['thumbnail-height']}}`